# df.rolling() not respecting gaps in the index?

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

Presume I have a dataframe with the following data:

| Index | var |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 4.49 |
| 101 | 7.58 |
| 102 | 4.76 |
| 103 | 4.48 |
| 104 | 5.13 |
| 105 | 7.24 |
| 106 | 4.69 |
| 107 | 4.78 |
| 108 | 4.19 |
| 205 | 9.34 |
| 206 | 11.10 |
| 207 | 9.15 |
| 208 | 10.01 |
| 209 | 11.64 |
| 210 | 13.93 |
| 211 | 12.99 |
| 212 | 13.30 |
| 213 | 9.32 |
| 214 | 4.53 |
| 215 | 11.13 |

As shown, the index has a typical resolution of 1, but has a gap between 108 and 205. This is just an example, in reality the dataframe will have several continuous (having res=1) sections, with any given gap size between them.

I would now like to perform rolling window operations, using df.rolling(), such as df.rolling(3).mean(). However, I notice that instead of creating the window based on the actual index values, the rolling operation seems to ignore the index and just sequentially grab values to satisfy the window size. Meaning, for example, you can have a window which includes the values for indices [108,108,205] or [108, 205, 206], etc.

How can I do this operation, but respect the index such that the window size refers specifically to the distance between values as indicated by the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed how [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) works. It considers consecutive values independently of the index values.

You could temporarily [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to have your desired behavior:

```
out = (df.reindex(range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()+1))
         .rolling(3).mean()
         .reindex(df.index)
      )
```

Output:

```
             var
Index           
100          NaN
101          NaN
102     5.610000
103     5.606667
104     4.790000
105     5.616667
106     5.686667
107     5.570000
108     4.553333
205          NaN
206          NaN
207     9.863333
208    10.086667
209    10.266667
210    11.860000
211    12.853333
212    13.406667
213    11.870000
214     9.050000
215     8.326667
```

Output with `rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()`:

```
             var
Index           
100     4.490000
101     6.035000
102     5.610000
103     5.606667
104     4.790000
105     5.616667
106     5.686667
107     5.570000
108     4.553333
205     9.340000
206    10.220000
207     9.863333
208    10.086667
209    10.266667
210    11.860000
211    12.853333
212    13.406667
213    11.870000
214     9.050000
215     8.326667
```